# How to find dependent libraries

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I got a C/C++ application, i need to determine all (shared) libraries on which it is dependent, so i can share it with other people along with libraries so they don't have to install any package, on Linux.

So is it possible to determine all libraries on which a C++ application is dependent?

A little clarification, i dont have application makefiles for the moment, thats why i have to find another way.

Comment: Try `ldd my_program`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think for linux you can use  **ldd command**. You can see the man page for this command or also find this here http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ldd.htm.

Comment: Thanks, Apoorva sahay

Answer (score 4):

Try to use ldd  which will list the dependent libraries for that executable